# Expected number of coin flips to get three heads or three tails

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables, expected-value

We both play a game where we flip a coin. You win if 3 heads appear, I win if 3 tails appear. What is the expected number of flips for the game to end.

The heads/tails doesn't need to be consecutive. Here's my approach:

First find the expected number of flips to get three heads before game ends. This can happen in either three or four of five tosses. So the expected value is
$$\frac{1}{2^3}*3 + \frac{1}{2^4}*4C_3*4 + \frac{1}{2^5}*5C_3*5 $$

Divide this value by 2 to get the answer. Is this correct?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can't follow your calculation.  If $p_i$ is the probability that the game ends on the $i^{th}$ round then the answer is $\sum_{i=3}^5 p_i\times i$, so you just need to compute $p_i$.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake in my computation. Does it make sense now?

Comment: No.  As I said, you need to compute $p_i$. I don't see where you even tried to do that.

Comment: $p_4 = \frac{1}{2^4}*4C_3$, for example.

Comment: No, it isn't.  Keep in mind that, in order for the game to take exactly $4$ rounds, it can't have ended in $3$.  Thus $HHTH$ is a good $4-$round game, but $HHHT$ is not.  Also, good to remember that $p_3+p_4+p_5$ must be $1$.

Comment: Ah, I see that is where I go wrong. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Ok so $p_3 = \frac{1}{2^3}, p_4 = \frac{1}{2^4}*3C_2, p_5 = \frac{1}{2^5}4C_2 $. Is that correct?

Comment: $p_3\neq \frac 18$.  There are $2$ ways the game can end in three turns.  Also, those numbers do not sum to $1$.

Comment: For some reason, you appear to just be focusing on games in which $H$ wins.  There is no advantage in that.

Comment: Yes I focused on H winning first, and then I just have to multiply by 2. For example, the expected value is $\frac{1}{2^3}*2*3 + \frac{1}{2^4}*2*3C_2*4 + \frac{1}{2^5}*2*4C_2*5 = 4.125$

Comment: So each $p_i$ is twice what you wrote.  Ok, though it seems needlessly confusing.  In any case, I agree with that result.

Comment: Indeed. Should've been clearer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Let $P(S)$ be the probability of a given sequence and let $N(S)$ be the number of flips in that sequence. You want to find $E(N(S)) = \sum_{S} P(S)N(S)$.

There are only finitely many possible games, namely, in alphabetical order:

1. $HHH: P = 1/8, N = 3$
2. $HHTH: P = 1/16, N = 4$
3. $HHTTH: P = 1/32, N = 5$
4. $HHTTT: P = 1/32, N = 5$
5. $HTHH: P = 1/16, N = 4$
6. $HTHTH: P = 1/32, N = 5$
7. $HTHTT: P = 1/32, N = 5$
8. $HTTHH: P = 1/32, N = 5$
9. $HTTHT: P = 1/32, N = 5$
10. $HTTT: P = 1/16, N = 4$
11. $THHH: P = 1/16, N = 4$
12. $THHTH: P = 1/32, N = 5$
13. $THHTT: P = 1/32, N = 5$
14. $THTHH: P = 1/32, N = 5$
15. $THTHT: P = 1/32, N = 5$
16. $THTT: P = 1/16, N = 4$
17. $TTHHH: P = 1/32, N = 5$
18. $TTHHT: P = 1/32, N = 5$
19. $TTHT: P = 1/16, N = 4$
20. $TTT: P = 1/8, N = 3$

Grouping these by $N$ we see that:

1. For $N = 3$ the total $P = 1/4$
2. For $N = 4$ the total $P = 3/8$
3. For $N = 5$ the total $P = 3/8$

So $E(N) = 3 \cdot 1/4 + 4 \cdot 3/8 + 5 \cdot 3/8 = 33/8 = 4.125$